# What's wrong with this code to sort Maps in CPP by value, using std::sort?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort a Map by value , using the std::sort and a custom compare function. 
But I get a compile error .

Ps: I don't want to use Lambda functions.

I have already tried using iterator variables as arguments in the dcompare function.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int foo(int n) {
        unordered_map<int,int> M ;
        // Inputs = {2,4,5,2,4,2,1}
        M[4] = 2;
        M[5] = 1;
        M[2] = 3;
        M[1] = 1;

        for(auto it : M){
            cout<<it.first<<" : "<<it.second<<endl;
        }

        sort(M.begin(), M.end(), dcompare);

        for(auto it : M){
            cout<<it.first<<" : "<<it.second<<endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }

private:
    static bool dcompare(const std::pair<int,int> itL, const std::pair<int,int> itR) {
        return (itL.second < itR.second);
    }
};
```

I get the same error when I changed the variables to iterators

```cpp
static bool dcompare(const map<int,int>::iterator itL, const map<int,int>::iterator itR) 
{ 
    return (itL->second < itR->second); 
}
```

This is the compiler error I got:

```
stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (*)(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)>]':
stl_algo.h:4866:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >; _Compare = bool (*)(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)]'
Line 15: Char 42:   required from here
stl_algo.h:1969:22: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >' and 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >')
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
```

Comment: `std::map` already has sorted keys.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to sort the map by value, as mentioned in my question. 
Also, I'm trying to learn how to do this for maps of other data types and not just int .

Comment: But can you tell us to what end, you want to spend the map by the values? Probably you need a they way map.

Comment: What you want won't work for several reasons. For example, `std::sort` requires random-access iterators which `std::map` doesn't supply. You need to think about another solution or data structure.

Comment: @RG46-fY3e Then you will have to transfer the data into another data structure since `std::map` sorts by key. You can transfer into a `std::vector<pair<T1,T2>>` and sort it there. You can also reverse the role of key/value and provide a custom comparison function. If many the map is not one-to-one (many values are the same), you can use `std::multimap` with a custom comparison function.

Comment: @RG46-fY3e -- You cannot interfere with the map's sorting criteria, except to tell it how to place its key/value pairs in a map when creating a `std::map` object.  I think you hit a roadblock by believing that the value part of the map will/can influence how the map stores its elements -- it doesn't.  There is nothing you can do with the value portion that will affect how a map stores its keys.  As another comment suggested, you either need to make a "mirror" of the map, where the values become the key, or you copy the values to another container and sort that container using `std::sort`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to re-order elements of a map. A `std::map` is ordered by the key, and a `std::unordered_map` is unordered, as the name implies.

The error itself tells you that `std::sort` tries to use the subtraction operator for the iterator, but that there is no such operator for a map iterator. This in turn tells you that a map iterator is not a random access iterator. `std::sort` requires the input iterators to be random access iterators.

A solution is to create an array of pointers to the elements of the map and sort the array. Or, you could move the elements themselves into the array if you no longer need the map. Or you could copy the elements.

Another solution is to use a multi-index container instead of a map. The standard library doesn't provide such containers however. A multi-index container can be implemented as a set of trees with shared nodes. One multi-node would have the children for each index-tree. So, one index could be the key lookup of your map, and another index could be sorted by the value.